# Vue.js trying to increment array value when adding new row

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I am trying to increment an array value when I add a new row in Vue.js, but I get the error:

> You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

The JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    inputs: [{
      id: 0,
      username: ''
    }],
  }),
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.inputs.push({ id: this.id++, username: '' });
    }
  }
});
```

The markup:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="input in inputs">
    <input :key="input.id" :name="'username_' + input.id" type="text" v- v-model="input.username" placeholder="username">
  </div>
  <button @click="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

However, if I hardcode the value in the add function it works the first time:

```
add() {
  this.inputs.push({ id: 1, username: '' });
}
```

So, how can I make it dynamic? Typing `id: this.id++` does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem :- **this.id** is undefined Vue doesn't know **id** because its not in the component data

so you have to options to solve your problem

- define the varaible id like this

  ```
  data(){
       id:0,inputs:[]
   }
  ```
- other option which will solve the problem and I prefer it is to replace this line of code

  ```
      this.inputs.push({ id: this.id++, username: '' });
  ```

  with this line

  ```
    this.inputs.push({ id: this.inputs.length, username: '' });
  ```

  this will solve the problem and here is the compelete code

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    inputs: [{
   id: 0,
   username: ''
}],
  }),
  methods: {
    add () {
      console.log(this.inputs.length);
      this.inputs.push({ id: this.inputs.length, username: '' });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="input in inputs">
      <input :key="input.id" :name="'username_' + input.id" type="text" v- v-model="input.username" placeholder="username">
    </div>
    <button @click="add">Add</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Had no clue I could use ``this.inputs.length`` like that, thought it would only output the current value, but I guess the object gets pushed into the array before that line runs?

Comment: Very nice! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even more simply:

Using the index. Work for me.

Enjoy!

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    inputs: [{
   username: ''
}],
  }),
  methods: {
    add () {
      this.inputs.push({ username: '' });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
      <input :name="'username_' + index" type="text" v-model="input.username" placeholder="username">
    </div>
    <button @click="add">Add</button>
  </div>
```